# Properly handle the new "Bootstrap Toast" feature in Angular 7+?

Tags: javascript, angular, bootstrap-4, angular7, bootstrap-toast

I am trying to use [Bootstrap 4.2 Toast](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/components/toasts/) with an Angular 7 application. I'm unable to translate Jquery sample provided by the Bootstrap documentation in Angular.

Currently, I use Jquery inside my HTML template that call `$('.toast').toast('show')` to show up all DOM toasts when my component is ready, but I'm sure that's the wrong way.
I would like to show up the toasts notifications on `ngOnInit()`, or another function I can call in a *.component.ts*.

For example, I want to show one toast notification.

**1 - Current method**

*toast.component.html*

```html
[...]

<div class="toast" id="toast" ...></div>

[...]
```

*index.html*

```html
[...]
<!-- Little hack to initialize Toast (according to the documentation) -->
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#toast').toast('show');
});
</script>
[...]
```

**2 - Desired method**

*toast.component.html*

```html
[...]

<div class="toast" id="toast" ...></div>

[...]
```

*toast.component.ts*

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  templateUrl: './toast.component.html'
})
export class ToastComponent implements OnInit {

  ngOnInit() {
    // Here is a good way to show a toast notification right here ?
  }

}
```

Here is a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7tqjf6) that show this current behaviour.

I know that's a recent feature, but if someone find a good way to handle Bootstrap Toasts, that'd be really appreciate :)

Comment: in general it's bad practice to use jquery and angular together and you should try to avoid it as much as you can.
ngx-toaster is great and really recommended 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-toastrnlibrary

Comment: @OrYaacov thanks you, I will see with this package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I've used [Toast module](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/toast/overview) from [ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home) library to accomplish this purpose :

```
<ngb-toast header="Notification header">
  Content of the notification
</ngb-toast>
```